# Not able to show progress dialog

Tags: android, android-asynctask, progressdialog

I am preparing an app. Initially i have to put big amount of data into the database. To achieve this, i have used `AsyncTask` as below:

This is my java code:

```
package com.hippieapp;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Locale;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;

public class Home extends Activity {

    static SQLiteDatabase database;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        if (!prefs.getBoolean("firstTime", false)) {

            new CheckTypesTask().execute();

            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
            editor.putBoolean("firstTime", true);
            editor.commit();
        }
    }

    private void insert_in_questions() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        loadDatabase();

        String currentDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd").format(Calendar
                .getInstance().getTime());
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

        values.put("question",
                "How many inch your hair long reaches past your shoulders ?");
        values.put("ans_type", "textinput");
        values.put("creation_date", currentDate);
        values.put("is_delete", "0");
        values.put("is_publish", "1");
        database.insert("questions", null, values);
        values.clear();

        values.put("question", "Are you male ?");
        values.put("ans_type", "yesno");
        values.put("creation_date", currentDate);
        values.put("is_delete", "0");
        values.put("is_publish", "1");
        database.insert("questions", null, values);
        values.clear();

        values.put("question",
                "For males- Have you gotten flack for having long hair ?");
        values.put("ans_type", "yesno");
        values.put("creation_date", currentDate);
        values.put("is_delete", "0");
        values.put("is_publish", "1");
        database.insert("questions", null, values);
        values.clear();

        values.put("question",
                "For Females- Have you gotten flack for wearing no makeup ?");
        values.put("ans_type", "yesno");
        values.put("creation_date", currentDate);
        values.put("is_delete", "0");
        values.put("is_publish", "1");
        database.insert("questions", null, values);
        values.clear();

        values.put("question",
                "Are you over the age of 40 and still have not cut your hair ?");
        values.put("ans_type", "yesno");
        values.put("creation_date", currentDate);
        values.put("is_delete", "0");
        values.put("is_publish", "1");
        database.insert("questions", null, values);
        values.clear();

        values.put(
                "question",
                "Do you have a brownie recipe that includes ingredients you can not get at the local A&P ?");
        values.put("ans_type", "yesno");
        values.put("creation_date", currentDate);
        values.put("is_delete", "0");
        values.put("is_publish", "1");
        database.insert("questions", null, values);
        values.clear();

        values.put(
                "question",
                "Is your dwelling is decorated with beads hanging from the door, a lava lamp or fillmore posters ?");
        values.put("ans_type", "yesno");
        values.put("creation_date", currentDate);
        values.put("is_delete", "0");
        values.put("is_publish", "1");
        database.insert("questions", null, values);
        values.clear();

        values.put("question",
                "Do you have a bean bag chair in your \"groovy pad\" ?");
        values.put("ans_type", "yesno");
        values.put("creation_date", currentDate);
        values.put("is_delete", "0");
        values.put("is_publish", "1");
        database.insert("questions", null, values);
        values.clear();

        values.put("question",
                "Does the bean bag chair is the only piece of furniture you have ?");
        values.put("ans_type", "yesno");
        values.put("creation_date", currentDate);
        values.put("is_delete", "0");
        values.put("is_publish", "1");
        database.insert("questions", null, values);
        values.clear();

        values.put("question", "Is your home decorated with homemade art ?");
        values.put("ans_type", "yesno");
        values.put("creation_date", currentDate);
        values.put("is_delete", "0");
        values.put("is_publish", "1");
        database.insert("questions", null, values);
        values.clear();

        values.put("question", "Do you do pottery ?");
        values.put("ans_type", "yesno");
        values.put("creation_date", currentDate);
        values.put("is_delete", "0");
        values.put("is_publish", "1");
        database.insert("questions", null, values);
        values.clear();

        values.put("question", "Do you know how to do macrame ?");
        values.put("ans_type", "yesno");
        values.put("creation_date", currentDate);
        values.put("is_delete", "0");
        values.put("is_publish", "1");
        database.insert("questions", null, values);
        values.clear();

        values.put("question", "Do you know how to do the macaroon ?");
        values.put("ans_type", "yesno");
        values.put("creation_date", currentDate);
        values.put("is_delete", "0");
        values.put("is_publish", "1");
        database.insert("questions", null, values);
        values.clear();

        values.put("question", "Did you were at Woodstock ?");
        values.put("ans_type", "yesno");
        values.put("creation_date", currentDate);
        values.put("is_delete", "0");
        values.put("is_publish", "1");
        database.insert("questions", null, values);
        values.clear();

        values.put("question",
                "Do you think you may have been at Woodstock, but aren't entirely sure ?");
        values.put("ans_type", "yesno");
        values.put("creation_date", currentDate);
        values.put("is_delete", "0");
        values.put("is_publish", "1");
        database.insert("questions", null, values);
        values.clear();

        values.put("question", "Who is your favorite Beatle ?");
        values.put("ans_type", "yesno");
        values.put("creation_date", currentDate);
        values.put("is_delete", "0");
        values.put("is_publish", "1");
        database.insert("questions", null, values);
        values.clear();

        values.put(
                "question",
                "Do you have fire drills to practice getting all your Grateful Dead tapes out of the house ?");
        values.put("ans_type", "yesno");
        values.put("creation_date", currentDate);
        values.put("is_delete", "0");
        values.put("is_publish", "1");
        database.insert("questions", null, values);
        values.clear();

        values.put(
                "question",
                "How many state line you've crossed on your longest road trip to see a 60s era musical artist or band in concert ?");
        values.put("ans_type", "yesno");
        values.put("creation_date", currentDate);
        values.put("is_delete", "0");
        values.put("is_publish", "1");
        database.insert("questions", null, values);
        values.clear();

        values.put("question",
                "Have you have traveled to another country to see such a band or artist ?");
        values.put("ans_type", "yesno");
        values.put("creation_date", currentDate);
        values.put("is_delete", "0");
        values.put("is_publish", "1");
        database.insert("questions", null, values);
        values.clear();

        values.put("question",
                "Were you were affected personally by Jerry Garcia's death ?");
        values.put("ans_type", "yesno");
        values.put("creation_date", currentDate);
        values.put("is_delete", "0");
        values.put("is_publish", "1");
        database.insert("questions", null, values);
        values.clear();

        values.put("question", "Do you know what bag you're in ?");
        values.put("ans_type", "yesno");
        values.put("creation_date", currentDate);
        values.put("is_delete", "0");
        values.put("is_publish", "1");
        database.insert("questions", null, values);
        values.clear();

        values.put("question", "Do you own an incense burner ?");
        values.put("ans_type", "yesno");
        values.put("creation_date", currentDate);
        values.put("is_delete", "0");
        values.put("is_publish", "1");
        database.insert("questions", null, values);
        values.clear();

        values.put("question", "Do you own, or have owned a VW bus ?");
        values.put("ans_type", "yesno");
        values.put("creation_date", currentDate);
        values.put("is_delete", "0");
        values.put("is_publish", "1");
        database.insert("questions", null, values);
        values.clear();

        values.put("question", "Is the bus painted multiple colors ?");
        values.put("ans_type", "yesno");
        values.put("creation_date", currentDate);
        values.put("is_delete", "0");
        values.put("is_publish", "1");
        database.insert("questions", null, values);
        values.clear();

        values.put("question", "Do you play the sitar ?");
        values.put("ans_type", "yesno");
        values.put("creation_date", currentDate);
        values.put("is_delete", "0");
        values.put("is_publish", "1");
        database.insert("questions", null, values);
        values.clear();

        values.put(
                "question",
                "Have you written a song protesting war, bucking the establishment, or containing a reference to illegal drugs ?");
        values.put("ans_type", "yesno");
        values.put("creation_date", currentDate);
        values.put("is_delete", "0");
        values.put("is_publish", "1");
        database.insert("questions", null, values);
        values.clear();

        values.put(
                "question",
                "Have you written songs about all three protesting war, bucking the establishment, or containing a reference to illegal drugs ?");
        values.put("ans_type", "yesno");
        values.put("creation_date", currentDate);
        values.put("is_delete", "0");
        values.put("is_publish", "1");
        database.insert("questions", null, values);
        values.clear();

        values.put("question", "Were you actually alive in the 1960s ?");
        values.put("ans_type", "yesno");
        values.put("creation_date", currentDate);
        values.put("is_delete", "0");
        values.put("is_publish", "1");
        database.insert("questions", null, values);
        values.clear();

        values.put("question",
                "Do you really, really wish you had been alive in the 1960s ?");
        values.put("ans_type", "yesno");
        values.put("creation_date", currentDate);
        values.put("is_delete", "0");
        values.put("is_publish", "1");
        database.insert("questions", null, values);
        values.clear();

        values.put("question", "Do you believe that \"All You Need is Love\" ?");
        values.put("ans_type", "yesno");
        values.put("creation_date", currentDate);
        values.put("is_delete", "0");
        values.put("is_publish", "1");
        database.insert("questions", null, values);
        values.clear();

        values.put("question", "Do you believe in good medical plan ?");
        values.put("ans_type", "yesno");
        values.put("creation_date", currentDate);
        values.put("is_delete", "0");
        values.put("is_publish", "1");
        database.insert("questions", null, values);
        values.clear();

        values.put("question",
                "Does the word \"trip\" not make you think of a vacation ?");
        values.put("ans_type", "yesno");
        values.put("creation_date", currentDate);
        values.put("is_delete", "0");
        values.put("is_publish", "1");
        database.insert("questions", null, values);
        values.clear();

        values.put("question",
                "Does the word \"man\" peppers your conversations ?");
        values.put("ans_type", "yesno");
        values.put("creation_date", currentDate);
        values.put("is_delete", "0");
        values.put("is_publish", "1");
        database.insert("questions", null, values);
        values.clear();

        values.put(
                "question",
                "Have you used the word \"groovy\" or the phrase \"Can you dig it ?\" with a straight face?");
        values.put("ans_type", "yesno");
        values.put("creation_date", currentDate);
        values.put("is_delete", "0");
        values.put("is_publish", "1");
        database.insert("questions", null, values);
        values.clear();

        values.put(
                "question",
                "Have you used words \"groovy\" and the phrase \"Can you dig it ?\" both in the same sentence ?");
        values.put("ans_type", "yesno");
        values.put("creation_date", currentDate);
        values.put("is_delete", "0");
        values.put("is_publish", "1");
        database.insert("questions", null, values);
        values.clear();

        values.put("question", "Have you taken part in a peace march ?");
        values.put("ans_type", "yesno");
        values.put("creation_date", currentDate);
        values.put("is_delete", "0");
        values.put("is_publish", "1");
        database.insert("questions", null, values);
        values.clear();

        values.put("question", "Have you started a petition ?");
        values.put("ans_type", "yesno");
        values.put("creation_date", currentDate);
        values.put("is_delete", "0");
        values.put("is_publish", "1");
        database.insert("questions", null, values);
        values.clear();

        values.put("question", "Have you taken part in a sit-in ?");
        values.put("ans_type", "yesno");
        values.put("creation_date", currentDate);
        values.put("is_delete", "0");
        values.put("is_publish", "1");
        database.insert("questions", null, values);
        values.clear();

        values.put(
                "question",
                "Have you \"taken part in a peace march\", \"started a petition\" and \"taken part in a sit-in\" all three ?");
        values.put("ans_type", "yesno");
        values.put("creation_date", currentDate);
        values.put("is_delete", "0");
        values.put("is_publish", "1");
        database.insert("questions", null, values);
        values.clear();

        values.put("question",
                "Have you ever received junk mail addressed to \"dear radical\" ?");
        values.put("ans_type", "yesno");
        values.put("creation_date", currentDate);
        values.put("is_delete", "0");
        values.put("is_publish", "1");
        database.insert("questions", null, values);
        values.clear();

        values.put("question",
                "Do you think \"social action\" is a frat party on a saturday night ?");
        values.put("ans_type", "yesno");
        values.put("creation_date", currentDate);
        values.put("is_delete", "0");
        values.put("is_publish", "1");
        database.insert("questions", null, values);
        values.clear();

        values.put(
                "question",
                "Have your children names like Windsong, Freedom or Peace Love Understanding Smith ?");
        values.put("ans_type", "yesno");
        values.put("creation_date", currentDate);
        values.put("is_delete", "0");
        values.put("is_publish", "1");
        database.insert("questions", null, values);
        values.clear();

        values.put("question",
                "Do you wish your parents had named you Peace Love Understanding Smith ?");
        values.put("ans_type", "yesno");
        values.put("creation_date", currentDate);
        values.put("is_delete", "0");
        values.put("is_publish", "1");
        database.insert("questions", null, values);
        values.clear();

        values.put("question",
                "Do you say \"thank you\" when someone calls you a hippy ?");
        values.put("ans_type", "yesno");
        values.put("creation_date", currentDate);
        values.put("is_delete", "0");
        values.put("is_publish", "1");
        database.insert("questions", null, values);
        values.clear();

        values.put(
                "question",
                "Do you say \"Groovy man, like, you think I'm a hippy? Far out, can you dig that?\"");
        values.put("ans_type", "yesno");
        values.put("creation_date", currentDate);
        values.put("is_delete", "0");
        values.put("is_publish", "1");
        database.insert("questions", null, values);
        values.clear();

        values.put("question", "Do you wear Birkenstocks ?");
        values.put("ans_type", "yesno");
        values.put("creation_date", currentDate);
        values.put("is_delete", "0");
        values.put("is_publish", "1");
        database.insert("questions", null, values);
        values.clear();

        values.put("question", "Do you make your own sandals ?");
        values.put("ans_type", "yesno");
        values.put("creation_date", currentDate);
        values.put("is_delete", "0");
        values.put("is_publish", "1");
        database.insert("questions", null, values);
        values.clear();

        values.put(
                "question",
                "Do you have a bumper sticker reading \"save the whales\", \"think green\" or has dancing bears on it ?");
        values.put("ans_type", "yesno");
        values.put("creation_date", currentDate);
        values.put("is_delete", "0");
        values.put("is_publish", "1");
        database.insert("questions", null, values);
        values.clear();

        values.put(
                "question",
                "Does bumper stickers like \"save the whales\", \"think green\" or has dancing bears on it; are holding your car together ?");
        values.put("ans_type", "yesno");
        values.put("creation_date", currentDate);
        values.put("is_delete", "0");
        values.put("is_publish", "1");
        database.insert("questions", null, values);
        values.clear();

        values.put("question", "Are you a vegetarian ?");
        values.put("ans_type", "yesno");
        values.put("creation_date", currentDate);
        values.put("is_delete", "0");
        values.put("is_publish", "1");
        database.insert("questions", null, values);
        values.clear();

        values.put(
                "question",
                "Does the only reason you call yourself a \"vegetarian\" is that you stopped eating Big Macs ?");
        values.put("ans_type", "yesno");
        values.put("creation_date", currentDate);
        values.put("is_delete", "0");
        values.put("is_publish", "1");
        database.insert("questions", null, values);
        values.clear();

        values.put("question", "Do you smell like patchouli ?");
        values.put("ans_type", "yesno");
        values.put("creation_date", currentDate);
        values.put("is_delete", "0");
        values.put("is_publish", "1");
        database.insert("questions", null, values);
        values.clear();

        values.put("question",
                "Have you have sold any hand-made item in the parking lot of a concert ?");
        values.put("ans_type", "yesno");
        values.put("creation_date", currentDate);
        values.put("is_delete", "0");
        values.put("is_publish", "1");
        database.insert("questions", null, values);
        values.clear();

        values.put("question", "Do you think money is the root of all evil ?");
        values.put("ans_type", "yesno");
        values.put("creation_date", currentDate);
        values.put("is_delete", "0");
        values.put("is_publish", "1");
        database.insert("questions", null, values);
        values.clear();

        values.put("question",
                "Do you add the phrase \"and may the devil smite me with it\" ?");
        values.put("ans_type", "yesno");
        values.put("creation_date", currentDate);
        values.put("is_delete", "0");
        values.put("is_publish", "1");
        database.insert("questions", null, values);
        values.clear();

        values.put("question",
                "Do you think Jim Morrison's poetry is profound ?");
        values.put("ans_type", "yesno");
        values.put("creation_date", currentDate);
        values.put("is_delete", "0");
        values.put("is_publish", "1");
        database.insert("questions", null, values);
        values.clear();

        values.put("question", "Do you think John Lennon's drawings are art ?");
        values.put("ans_type", "yesno");
        values.put("creation_date", currentDate);
        values.put("is_delete", "0");
        values.put("is_publish", "1");
        database.insert("questions", null, values);
        values.clear();

        values.put("question", "Do you like Bob Dylan's singing voice ?");
        values.put("ans_type", "yesno");
        values.put("creation_date", currentDate);
        values.put("is_delete", "0");
        values.put("is_publish", "1");
        database.insert("questions", null, values);
        values.clear();

        values.put("question",
                "Have you ever heard of Jim Morrison, John Lennon or Bob Dylan?");
        values.put("ans_type", "yesno");
        values.put("creation_date", currentDate);
        values.put("is_delete", "0");
        values.put("is_publish", "1");
        database.insert("questions", null, values);
        values.clear();

        values.put(
                "question",
                "Do you have a necklace with either wooden beads, seeds, a peace or yin yang symbol ?");
        values.put("ans_type", "yesno");
        values.put("creation_date", currentDate);
        values.put("is_delete", "0");
        values.put("is_publish", "1");
        database.insert("questions", null, values);
        values.clear();

        values.put(
                "question",
                "Do you have \"wooden beads\", \"seeds\" and \"a peace or yin yang symbol\" all together ?");
        values.put("ans_type", "yesno");
        values.put("creation_date", currentDate);
        values.put("is_delete", "0");
        values.put("is_publish", "1");
        database.insert("questions", null, values);
        values.clear();

        values.put(
                "question",
                "Did you use to have \"wooden beads\", \"seeds\" and \"a peace or yin yang symbol\" all of the three but you gave them away or traded them for concert tickets");
        values.put("ans_type", "yesno");
        values.put("creation_date", currentDate);
        values.put("is_delete", "0");
        values.put("is_publish", "1");
        database.insert("questions", null, values);
        values.clear();

        values.put(
                "question",
                "Does your computer screen name or password is related to a 60s musical performer ?");
        values.put("ans_type", "yesno");
        values.put("creation_date", currentDate);
        values.put("is_delete", "0");
        values.put("is_publish", "1");
        database.insert("questions", null, values);
        values.clear();

        values.put(
                "question",
                "Are the only CDs or records in your collection that were recorded after 1980 were recorded by artists who were most famous in the 60s or 70s ?");
        values.put("ans_type", "yesno");
        values.put("creation_date", currentDate);
        values.put("is_delete", "0");
        values.put("is_publish", "1");
        database.insert("questions", null, values);
        values.clear();

        values.put("question", "Have you been to San Francisco ?");
        values.put("ans_type", "yesno");
        values.put("creation_date", currentDate);
        values.put("is_delete", "0");
        values.put("is_publish", "1");
        database.insert("questions", null, values);
        values.clear();

        values.put("question", "Have you wore flowers in your hair ?");
        values.put("ans_type", "yesno");
        values.put("creation_date", currentDate);
        values.put("is_delete", "0");
        values.put("is_publish", "1");
        database.insert("questions", null, values);
        values.clear();

        values.put("question", "Have you lived in a commune ?");
        values.put("ans_type", "yesno");
        values.put("creation_date", currentDate);
        values.put("is_delete", "0");
        values.put("is_publish", "1");
        database.insert("questions", null, values);
        values.clear();

        values.put(
                "question",
                "Have you quit the commune because you were tired of being the one to do all the work ?");
        values.put("ans_type", "yesno");
        values.put("creation_date", currentDate);
        values.put("is_delete", "0");
        values.put("is_publish", "1");
        database.insert("questions", null, values);
        values.clear();

        values.put("question", "Do you own a tie dyed article of clothing ?");
        values.put("ans_type", "yesno");
        values.put("creation_date", currentDate);
        values.put("is_delete", "0");
        values.put("is_publish", "1");
        database.insert("questions", null, values);
        values.clear();

        values.put("question", "Did you dye article of clothing yourself ?");
        values.put("ans_type", "yesno");
        values.put("creation_date", currentDate);
        values.put("is_delete", "0");
        values.put("is_publish", "1");
        database.insert("questions", null, values);
        values.clear();

        values.put("question", "Do you own any clothing items made of hemp ?");
        values.put("ans_type", "yesno");
        values.put("creation_date", currentDate);
        values.put("is_delete", "0");
        values.put("is_publish", "1");
        database.insert("questions", null, values);
        values.clear();

        values.put(
                "question",
                "Have you practiced Transcendental Meditation, have seriously studied Eastern religion, or been a Jesus freak ?");
        values.put("ans_type", "yesno");
        values.put("creation_date", currentDate);
        values.put("is_delete", "0");
        values.put("is_publish", "1");
        database.insert("questions", null, values);
        values.clear();

        values.put(
                "question",
                "Have you done \"practiced Transcendental Meditation\", \"have seriously studied Eastern religion\", and \"been a Jesus freak\" all of the these ?");
        values.put("ans_type", "yesno");
        values.put("creation_date", currentDate);
        values.put("is_delete", "0");
        values.put("is_publish", "1");
        database.insert("questions", null, values);
        values.clear();

        values.put("question",
                "Have you had a chemically induced spiritual experience ?");
        values.put("ans_type", "yesno");
        values.put("creation_date", currentDate);
        values.put("is_delete", "0");
        values.put("is_publish", "1");
        database.insert("questions", null, values);
        values.clear();
      .
      .
      .

    }

    private void create_database_and_tables() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        database = openOrCreateDatabase("HippieDatabase.db",
                SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY, null);
        database.setLocale(Locale.getDefault());
        database.setVersion(1);

        String create_table_questions = "create table if not exists questions (q_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
                + "question TEXT, "
                + "ans_type TEXT, "
                + "creation_date TEXT, "
                + "is_delete INTEGER, "
                + "is_publish INTEGER);";
        database.execSQL(create_table_questions);

        String create_table_answer_option = "create table if not exists answer_option (ao_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
                + "q_id INTEGER, "
                + "ans_option TEXT, "
                + "ans_point INTEGER, "
                + "is_delete INTEGER, "
                + "is_publish INTEGER);";
        database.execSQL(create_table_answer_option);
    }

    private void loadDatabase() {

        database = openOrCreateDatabase("HippieDatabase.db",
                SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE, null);
    }

    class CheckTypesTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        ProgressDialog Asycdialog = new ProgressDialog(Home.this);
        String typeStatus;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {

            Asycdialog.setMessage("First time initialization. Please wait...");
            Asycdialog.show();
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

            create_database_and_tables();

            insert_in_questions();

//          insert_in_answer_option();

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

            database.close();
            Asycdialog.dismiss();

            super.onPostExecute(result);
        }
    }

//  public void insert_in_answer_option() {
//      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
//      
//      
//  }
}
```

As you see, i have done 76 entries in the database, but still i am not able to view the `ProgressDialog`. There is still more data to be inserted on the first run of application.

Can anyone tell me why ? Is there any thing wrong with code, or the data is not that big enough to show `ProgressDialog` ? Please help me. This is the first time i have done work with `AsyncTask`.

Comment: try adding a Thread.sleep(); to make sure that the progress dialog is working properly.

Generally inserting of 76 entries will not take more that few msec.

Comment: can u please give me a code snippet in my code where to write the code, Thread.sleep();

Comment: try writing it in insert_in_questions(), when some of the inserts are done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`super.onPreExecute()` must be the first instruction in your on `onPreExecute` method

Comment: Okay, now its working. Thanks... is the same problem with 'onPostExecute()', i mean super.onPostExecute() must be called first ?

Comment: Yes you have to do the same thing in your `onPostExecute()` method

Comment: Okay i corrected the onPostExecute() before running. Now its showing. Thank you for helping me. I will make sure i dont make this mistake in future. Thanks.